# How do we to get JSON content in the response body of freshservice webservice?

Tags: json, api, web-services, vbscript, webservice-client

I am doing automation to get opening tickets details so i am executing web service call in FreshService ticketing tool.

Below is my web service call using CURL and GET

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -v -i 'https://support.XXXXXXX.com/helpdesk/tickets/9725.json?-u=ASDDDECDFF%3AX%20'
```

When i am executing only getting below response in body.

```
{
  "require_login":True
}
```

But my output joson file visible after opening that url in browse i can see json file, so i execute below vbsctipt to send HTTP request for read the JSON file but same ""Require_login":True" coming.

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "https://support.XXXXXXX.com/helpdesk/tickets/9723.json", False
o.send
msgbox o.responseText
```

So my expectation to get JSON file in body part of web service response or through vbscript get JSON file store locally.

Appreciate any other light wight tool or easy approach. More about Fresh service API details https://api.freshservice.com/#introduction

Comment: Well it’s telling you the service requires authentication, check through the documentation to see what is required to authenticate. Usually an API Key or a form of encoded username password string needs to be passed in the HTTP Headers but implementations vary. The section of the documentation - [“How does it work? Who can access my helpdesk? Can everybody see my data?”](https://api.freshservice.com/#authentication) appears to explain this.

Comment: yes your correct issue with authentication. now its working@Lankymart

Answer (score 0):

After i encoded my authentication key with base64 and addd Authorization as header and its working now.

Update Web service URL,

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXYYYYYZZZ' -v -i 'https://support.XXXXX.com/helpdesk/tickets.json'
```